# How to host jsp-website(pages) on server?

Tags: java, jsp, webserver

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"
 import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%@ include file="top.jsp"%>
```

I got the above error while hosting my jsp-website(pages) on server like network solutions. So, anyone have idea how to host jsp-website on server?

Comment: Is it a server LIKE network solutions or IS it a network solutions server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an error. It's the actual file you uploaded. You have to pick a web host which provides JSP hosting (on Tomcat or some other servlet container). Such hosts usually are a bit more expensive since most servlet containers isn't fit for mass hosting in the same way as for example CGI and scripting languages.

If your host have a JSP hosting service, contact the support and ask them for help.

Comment: hi,yeah ur right but actually we have uploaded our jsp site on server(like Network Solutions) except this error our site working properly....so,what could be right solution for the same...thanks in advance

Comment: <a href="http://www.networksolutions.com/web-hosting/index.jsp">     This is server</a> on this we are trying to host'

Answer (score 3):

`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %> <%@ include file="top.jsp"%>`

Is not an error. If this line is the output (what you see in your browser), than the page is just not rendered.

---

If you own an network solutions server, then you need the "nsHosting™ Shared (Unlimited)" Package for JSP support. The smaller once (small & large) does not support JPS.

@see [Compare Our Web Hosting Packages](http://www.networksolutions.com/web-hosting/hosting-package-comparison.jsp) and click "Expand All Technical Features"

Comment: yeah you are right..So what would be right solution for it.?i am using above server for hosting.....

Comment: @Smith: see my extended answer

Comment: we have upgraded that one but still giving same probs..:(

Comment: @Smith: This file belong to an application, and this application must be deployed in an web container (Apache Tomcat for example).